# Running new thread from within a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, tree, runnable

I have a puzzle that I solved. I will try to briefly describe it and then ask question.

Map phone numbers to text. For example:
101 -> 101, but 501 -> J01, K01, L01 (AFAIK).

We get 9digit number and need to produce all combination, even those that are not grammaticaly correct.

I created a program that basically grows like a tree. When a number that is not 0 or 1 is found we create a new branch with already translated text + one of possible letters + rest of number.

I solved it by creating a new thread every time new translateable digit is encountered.

Do you think it is a bad practice? Can it be solved better?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain why 501->J01 ?

Comment: if it runs recursively and may produce exponential number of threads then I think it makes no sense, it will bring no benefits, and you should pay much attention to proper synchronization between these threads - they have to check "if that part of the tree was already calculated" in a synchronized way so that they don't repeat same tasks

Comment: yes, because on phone keyboard under 5 you have "JKL" letters.

Comment: @KamilMikolajczyk
How do you think it could try to calculate the same part of the tree again?

Comment: `Do you think it is a bad practice?`---absolutely. Thread is heavyweight, you don't start it to process just one string.

Comment: So it's better to just let it call itself recursively?

Comment: You can submit tasks to an ExecutorService. That way you 1) optimally exploit concurrency and 2) don't face stack overflow issues.

Comment: Won't it run threads anyway?

Comment: One for each task? Certainly not---unless you misconfigure it.

Comment: One thread for taking care of transofrmations on one tree level, then submit outputs to ExecutorService for fruther transofmations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a thread for each possibility seems like overkill, what you really want is recursion.  Try this:

```
String [] lookup = { "0", "1", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQRS", "TUV", "WXYZ" };

List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

void translatePhone(String phoneNumber, int position) {
    int index = Integer.parseInt(phoneNumber.substring(position, position + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < lookup[index].length; i++) {
        String xlated = phoneNumber.substring(0, position) + lookup[index].charAt(i) + phoneNumber.substring(position + 1);
        if (position + 1 == phoneNumber.length) {
            results.add(xlated);
        } else {
            translatePhone(xlated, position + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Call `translatePhone(phoneString, 0)` to start it off.  Once that returns `results` should have all your results.

Comment: Looks really neat and it's basically the same solution as mine but without Threads. Thanks.